# Converting CSV File to JSON Format

Tags: c#, json, csv

I am working toward converting a CSV file over to JSON format (for a chart control).

The format that I need the data in for JSON is below:

```
var dataRetrievedfromCSV = [
    {
        "datalabel": "Humidity",
        "time": "1:54",
        "value": 78.4
    },
    {
        "datalabel": "Temperature",
        "time": "1:00",
        "value": 9.2
    },
    {
        "datalabel": "Temperature",
        "time": "2:12",
        "value": 16.4
    },
    {
        "datalabel": "Humidity",
        "time": "2:30",
        "value": 78.2
      }
    ];
```

The CSV is in a format, in which the times are left-most column, while the header information (labels) are the top row. (screenshot below)

[image]

I am having trouble parsing the CSV in a way, in which the headers are constant along with the time while containing all the values.

Here is my current code:

```
 public ActionResult GraphResults(string filePathT, int testNumber)
    {
        string filePath = filePathT;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        List<object> graphItems = new List<object>();

        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            bool firstRow = true;
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] currentRow = parser.ReadFields();

                if (firstRow) //check for header row
                {
                    foreach (string fields in currentRow)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(fields, typeof(string));
                    }

             
                    continue;
                }

                //Create new data rows under header

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                for (int c = 0; c < currentRow.Count(); c++)
                {
                    dr[c] = currentRow[c];
                }
               

            }
        }

         //once we have the datatable, attempt to organize for CSV?
         foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                graphItems.Add(new
                {
                    VALS = new
                    {
                        datalabel = ?,
                        time = ?,
                        value = ?
                    }
                };

            })             
                
        }
}
```

I successfully convert the CSV over to a datatable in c#, but I am still (in the second part of the code) having trouble creating the JSON object that is in the right format.

graphItems is a List, but I am open to any method of organizating / creating the JSON format.

I have tried simply Serializing the entire datatable as JSON, but this fails as the format returned does not include the label, or time for each datapoint.

Comment: What you posted is a grid screenshot, not a CSV file. CSV files are text. The headers in a CSV file don't have multiple rows. What does the *actual* file look like? Post an actual example *as text*, not images. Your desired JSON maps headers to completely different `datalabel` values, which means you'll need to map them using, eg a Dictionary. The structure itself is different and requires converting the CSV's wide format to a long format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably convert your data to objects rather than a data grid. This should help to ensure the data is valid:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime TestTime{ get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For parsing the csv file you should probably use a library, like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("myFile.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```

You likely need to configure the reader to map columns to properties, using indices or column header name. It also looks like you have two rows of headers, so you might need to read the first row to ignore it. Read the documentation for details.

You can then create a class for the values you want to export:

```
public class Bar{
    public string datalabel {get;set;}
    public double value {get;set;}
    ...
    public Bar(Foo foo){
        datalabel = foo.datalabel;
        value = foo.value;
    }
}
```

and map all of your objects:

```
var bars = records.Select(r => new Bar(r)).ToList();
```

and finally serialize the object list using some library, like [system.text.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(bars);
```